# Convex Hull and Thresholding for Colored Object Detection

Tags: c++, opencv, detection

I am currently trying to use OpenCV version 2.4.10 to detect red colored cups. I am new to OpenCV so I am starting with example code and trying to work my way from there. My idea was to utilize thresholding to first find any red objects on the frame. From there I wish to find the convex hull of those objects to detect which ones are actually cups (have a smaller bottom contour line than top). I am having trouble combining the convex hull code with the thresholding code that I had working prior however. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong and also point me in the right direction if my approach to this project seems off? Thank you!

Here is my code so far:

```
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int thresh = 100;
int max_thresh = 255;
RNG rng(12345);

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    cout << "Program Starts Here." << endl;
    VideoCapture cap(0); //capture the video from webcam

    if (!cap.isOpened())  // if not success, exit program
    {
        cout << "Cannot open the web cam" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    //namedWindow("Control", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE); //create a window called "Control"

    int iLowH = 170;
    int iHighH = 179;
    int iLowS = 150;
    int iHighS = 255;

    int iLowV = 60;
    int iHighV = 255;

    //Create trackbars in "Control" window
//  createTrackbar("LowH", "Control", &iLowH, 179); //Hue (0 - 179)
//  createTrackbar("HighH", "Control", &iHighH, 179);

//  createTrackbar("LowS", "Control", &iLowS, 255); //Saturation (0 - 255)
//  createTrackbar("HighS", "Control", &iHighS, 255);

//  createTrackbar("LowV", "Control", &iLowV, 255);//Value (0 - 255)
//  createTrackbar("HighV", "Control", &iHighV, 255);

    int iLastX = -1;
    int iLastY = -1;

    //Capture a temporary image from the camera
    Mat imgTmp;
    cap.read(imgTmp);

    //Create a black image with the size as the camera output
    Mat imgLines = Mat::zeros(imgTmp.size(), CV_8UC3);;


    while (true)
    {
        Mat imgOriginal;

        bool bSuccess = cap.read(imgOriginal); // read a new frame from video



        if (!bSuccess) //if not success, break loop
        {
            cout << "Cannot read a frame from video stream" << endl;
            break;
        }

        Mat imgHSV;

        cvtColor(imgOriginal, imgHSV, COLOR_BGR2HSV); //Convert the captured frame from BGR to HSV

        Mat imgThresholded;

        inRange(imgHSV, Scalar(iLowH, iLowS, iLowV), Scalar(iHighH, iHighS, iHighV), imgThresholded); //Threshold the image

        //morphological opening (removes small objects from the foreground)
        erode(imgThresholded, imgThresholded, getStructuringElement(MORPH_ELLIPSE, Size(5, 5)));
        dilate(imgThresholded, imgThresholded, getStructuringElement(MORPH_ELLIPSE, Size(5, 5)));

        //morphological closing (removes small holes from the foreground)
        dilate(imgThresholded, imgThresholded, getStructuringElement(MORPH_ELLIPSE, Size(5, 5)));
        erode(imgThresholded, imgThresholded, getStructuringElement(MORPH_ELLIPSE, Size(5, 5)));
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////START OF ADDED CONVEX HULL CODE       
        Mat threshold_output;
        vector<vector<Point> > contours;
        vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;

        /// Detect edges using Threshold
        threshold(imgThresholded, threshold_output, thresh, 255, THRESH_BINARY);

        /// Find contours
        findContours(threshold_output, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE,   
        Point(0, 0));

        /// Find the convex hull object for each contour
        vector<vector<Point> >hull(contours.size());
        for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
        {
            convexHull(Mat(contours[i]), hull[i], false);
        }
        /// Draw contours + hull results
        Mat drawing = Mat::zeros(threshold_output.size(), CV_8UC3);
        for (int i = 0; i< contours.size(); i++)
        {
            Scalar color = Scalar(rng.uniform(0, 255), rng.uniform(0, 255), rng.uniform(0, 255));
            drawContours(drawing, contours, i, color, 1, 8, vector<Vec4i>(), 0, Point());
            drawContours(drawing, hull, i, color, 1, 8, vector<Vec4i>(), 0, Point());
        }

        /// Show in a window
        namedWindow("Convex Hull", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
        imshow("Convex Hull", drawing);
///END OF ADDED CODE
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        //Calculate the moments of the thresholded image
        Moments oMoments = moments(imgThresholded);

        double dM01 = oMoments.m01;
        double dM10 = oMoments.m10;
        double dArea = oMoments.m00;

        // if the area <= 10000, I consider that the there are no object in the image and it's because of the noise, the area is not zero 
        if (dArea > 10000)
        {
            //calculate the position of the object
            int posX = dM10 / dArea;
            int posY = dM01 / dArea;
            cout << "X = " << posX << endl;
            cout << "Y = " << posY << endl;
            if (posX > 275 && posX < 325){
                cout << "Object Straight Ahead." << endl;
            }
            else if (posX < 275){
                cout << "Turn Left." << endl;
            }
            else if (posX > 325){
                cout << "Turn Right." << endl;
            }

            if (iLastX >= 0 && iLastY >= 0 && posX >= 0 && posY >= 0)
            {
                //Draw a red line from the previous point to the current point (for visual debugging)
                line(imgLines, Point(posX, posY), Point(iLastX, iLastY), Scalar(0, 0, 255), 2);
            }

            iLastX = posX;
            iLastY = posY;
        }

        imshow("Thresholded Image", imgThresholded); //show the thresholded image

        imgOriginal = imgOriginal + imgLines;
        imshow("Original", imgOriginal); //show the original image

        if (waitKey(30) == 27) //wait for 'esc' key press for 30ms. If 'esc' key is pressed, break loop
        {
            cout << "esc key is pressed by user" << endl;
            break;
        }

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you say more about what is "not working"?

Comment: I am getting an error "HEAP[OpenCV.exe]: Invalid address specified to RtlFreeHeap( 00000000002A0000, 0000000004044170 )" 

I was just running through it again and the camera capture frame would come up but once a red item came on screen I would receive that error.